# QSS и SVG. Почему не отображаются тени?

Tags: css, qt, svg

Суть проблемы: 
Есть SVG-картинки с тенями, которые я навешиваю на виджеты посредством Style Sheets.
При отрисовке у картинок почему-то не отображаются тени. 
Одна из картинок, для примера:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="406px" height="236px" viewBox="0 0 406 236" style="enable-background:new 0 0 406 236;" xml:space="preserve">
<defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10"/>
        <feOffset dx="0" dy="1" result="offsetblur"/>
    </filter>
</defs>
<g>
    <path fill="#FA1414" fill-opacity="1" style="filter:url(#dropshadow)" d="M3,231.606V14.383c0-0.77,0.597-1.394,1.333-1.394h156.128c6.938,0,13.473-4.236,18.655-9.59
        C179.365,3.143,179.696,3,180.046,3h23.119h22.794c0.347,0,0.67,0.138,0.919,0.39c4.575,4.644,12.949,9.599,19.025,9.599h155.764
        c0.736,0,1.333,0.624,1.333,1.394v217.223c0,0.77-0.597,1.394-1.333,1.394H4.333C3.597,233,3,232.376,3,231.606z"/>
    <path fill="#EFEFEF" d="M3,231.606V14.383c0-0.77,0.597-1.394,1.333-1.394h156.128c6.938,0,13.473-4.236,18.655-9.59
        C179.365,3.143,179.696,3,180.046,3h23.119h22.794c0.347,0,0.67,0.138,0.919,0.39c4.575,4.644,12.949,9.599,19.025,9.599h155.764
        c0.736,0,1.333,0.624,1.333,1.394v217.223c0,0.77-0.597,1.394-1.333,1.394H4.333C3.597,233,3,232.376,3,231.606z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Qt вообще умеет в SVG без своих QtSvg-классов?

UPD:
Картинка в браузере:
[image: Картинка в браузере:]

Та же картинка, открытая в qt-шном примере (SVG Viewer Example):
[image: Та же картинка, открытая в qt-шном примере (SVG Viewer Example)]

Если же натягивать файл так:

```
w->setStyleSheet("TWidgetSearchCategoriesView{ border-image: url(:/NewGraphics/catalog_bg.svg); }");
```

то тени нет вообще.

Разница большая. А хотелось бы, чтобы везде отображалось так, как в браузере.

Comment: Вопрос, чтобы понять, чего вы хотите получить в результате. Запустите в браузере чисто svg файл, без таблицы стилей. Вас всё устраивает в таком виде, как  есть?  Что у вас не отображается,- розовая тень или она плохо размывается? Дополните вопрос конкретикой.

Comment: @Alexandr_T, дополнил

Comment: На картинке в браузере слева нет тени. Это так устраивает или желательно, чтобы тень была тоже?

Comment: @Alexandr_T, устраивает

Answer (score 3):

Для того, чтобы фильтр  работал, ему нужно правильно задать [Filter effects region](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#FilterEffectsRegion)

по умолчанию: `x="-10%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="120%"` то есть, если ничего 
не прописывать, то будут эти значения. В большинстве случаев этого достаточно, чтобы фильтр работал. Если часть изображения не попадает в зону действия фильтра, то она обрезается.  Поэтому поиграйтесь с этими параметрами.

Еще одна неточность у вас: когда явно указывается `filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"`, то значения `x`,`y`, `width,`height` нужно указывать в пикселях.

По умолчанию    `filterUnits="objectBoundingBox"`

вот при этом значении нужно писать в процентах. `width="100%"`
То есть, в итоге можно не указывать эти все значения

```
 <filter id="dropshadow"  >
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10"/>
        <feOffset dx="0" dy="1" result="offsetblur"/>
    </filter>
```

пробовать так встроить в ваше приложение. Если не появится тень, то пробуйте увеличивать значения width, height в процентах при `filterUnits="objectBoundingBox"`

Либо в пикселях при `filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"`

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="406px" height="236px" viewBox="0 0 406 236"  >
<defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow"  >
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10"/>
        <feOffset dx="0" dy="1" result="offsetblur"/>
    </filter>
</defs>
<g>
    <path fill="#FA1414" fill-opacity="1" style="filter:url(#dropshadow)" d="M3,231.606V14.383c0-0.77,0.597-1.394,1.333-1.394h156.128c6.938,0,13.473-4.236,18.655-9.59
        C179.365,3.143,179.696,3,180.046,3h23.119h22.794c0.347,0,0.67,0.138,0.919,0.39c4.575,4.644,12.949,9.599,19.025,9.599h155.764
        c0.736,0,1.333,0.624,1.333,1.394v217.223c0,0.77-0.597,1.394-1.333,1.394H4.333C3.597,233,3,232.376,3,231.606z"/>
    <path fill="#EFEFEF" d="M3,231.606V14.383c0-0.77,0.597-1.394,1.333-1.394h156.128c6.938,0,13.473-4.236,18.655-9.59
        C179.365,3.143,179.696,3,180.046,3h23.119h22.794c0.347,0,0.67,0.138,0.919,0.39c4.575,4.644,12.949,9.599,19.025,9.599h155.764
        c0.736,0,1.333,0.624,1.333,1.394v217.223c0,0.77-0.597,1.394-1.333,1.394H4.333C3.597,233,3,232.376,3,231.606z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Для наглядности добавил красную рамку - это область действия svg. 
Элемент svg немного уменьшил   для расширения действия фильтра 
 `<g transform="scale(0.95)">`

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="406px" height="236px" viewBox="0 0 406 236" style="border:1px solid red;" >
<defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow"  >
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10"/>
        <feOffset dx="0" dy="1" result="offsetblur"/>
    </filter>
</defs>
<g transform="scale(0.95)">
    <path fill="#FA1414" fill-opacity="1" style="filter:url(#dropshadow)" d="M3,231.606V14.383c0-0.77,0.597-1.394,1.333-1.394h156.128c6.938,0,13.473-4.236,18.655-9.59
        C179.365,3.143,179.696,3,180.046,3h23.119h22.794c0.347,0,0.67,0.138,0.919,0.39c4.575,4.644,12.949,9.599,19.025,9.599h155.764
        c0.736,0,1.333,0.624,1.333,1.394v217.223c0,0.77-0.597,1.394-1.333,1.394H4.333C3.597,233,3,232.376,3,231.606z"/>
    <path fill="#EFEFEF" d="M3,231.606V14.383c0-0.77,0.597-1.394,1.333-1.394h156.128c6.938,0,13.473-4.236,18.655-9.59
        C179.365,3.143,179.696,3,180.046,3h23.119h22.794c0.347,0,0.67,0.138,0.919,0.39c4.575,4.644,12.949,9.599,19.025,9.599h155.764
        c0.736,0,1.333,0.624,1.333,1.394v217.223c0,0.77-0.597,1.394-1.333,1.394H4.333C3.597,233,3,232.376,3,231.606z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: спасибо за совет.
Поигрался. Изменения параметров x,y, width,height не дают никакого эффекта при отображении в Qt. Видимо, все-таки, это особенность самого Qt.

Comment: @GrinL. впечатление такое, см. рисунок 2, что просто не хватает пространства для срабатывания фильтра. Может как-то расширить контейнер, куда помещается в итоге svg    filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" написал?

Comment: я тоже так подумал, но так и не смог пока что найти возможности для изменения области отрисовки изображения, которое дало бы нужный мне эффект. Да и хочется все-таки через Style Sheets это дело натянуть.

Comment: @Grin L. сейчас добавлю пример

Comment: скопировал код svg из примера. В браузере красную рамку увидел. Переношу в Qt - никаких изменений. Рамки нет, тень еле видна.

Comment: @GrinL. Значит вывод однозначный - надо расширять в Qt место хранения svg и... как-то надо благодарить за потраченное время, для этого на stackoverflow предусмотрена система плюсов и чекбоксов

Comment: я бы с радостью, но, похоже, мне не хватает репутации.

Comment: 15 надо, говорит. 
А галочку ставить не хочется - вдруг придет кто-то из тех, кто работал с Qt, и подскажет-расскажет. Ответа на свой вопрос я пока не получил.

Comment: @Grin L Если найдете ответ,-  почему идет обрезка svg в Qt, пожалуйста опубликуйте здесь решение, мне по крайней мере будет интересно, да и другим надеюсь будет полезно.